# Does specifying 'language' attribute in HTML anchor changes events behavior?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JS code on my site:

```
function foo(link) {
    alert('ID=' + link.DocumentID + '; Lang=' + link.Language);
}
```

which should be called on each click on the following link:

```
<a href='http://www.example.com' DocumentID='someDocId' Language='en' onclick='foo(this);'>Example page</a>
```

(this is just a simplified version of my actual code, but it works exactly the same; I needed few nonstandard attributes, like `DocumentID` and `Language` for tracking purposes).

The problem is that `foo()` function does not fire on click event. When I changed the `Language` attribute name to i.e. `Lng` function everything works fine. I've tested it on IE7/8 and FF (the most current version).

According to [W3C HTML4 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A) `Language` attribute is not valid for anchor tag. I know it's valid for `<script>` tag but I don't see any relation.

Does anybody know why setting the `Language` attribute prevented from firing `onclick` event (I haven't tried with other event types but they also could be affected)?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Presumably you are testing in a browser with supports an unofficial extension to HTML which conflicts with the unofficial extension to HTML you are making (thus being a good demonstration of why extending HTML outside the standards process is Not A Good Idea).

Comment: Tat's not how you access attributes.  You should use `link.getAttribute('DocumentID')` and `link.getAttribute('Language')`

Comment: If you need custom attributes, use `data-*` attributes.

Comment: You forgot the `function` keyword: `function foo ( link ) { ...`

Comment: Are you seeing any JS errors in your console / debugging tools? I'd expect to see a syntax error for the missing `function` keyword. If not, then there should be an error for the `onclick` when you click.

Comment: Šime Vidas - thank you for notice; nevertheless the syntax error was only in example I provided, and this is not the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only IE 7/8 synchronizes custom attributes and properties.

```
link.href; // 'http://www.example.com'
link.language; // undefined (except in IE 7/8)
```

It's preferable to use *getAttribute*:

```
link.getAttribute('href'); // 'http://www.example.com'
link.getAttribute('language'); // 'en'
```

Attributes are case-insensitive in HTML, and case-sensitive in XML documents (including XHTML).

Don't confuse deprecated *language* attribute on *HTMLScriptElement* with *lang* attribute on *HTMLElement*.

P.S. Like someone already said, it's better to use HTML5 *data-* attributes*.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - you have right, the way I was accessing the attributes was wrong. But this is not the case - I can omit the JS code in `foo()` and `onclick` will still be "dead"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the language of your link, what about using this attribute instead?

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-hreflang

Comment: I don't want to specify the language of my link - I just want to put some additional meta-data to the link tag to use in function, that will be used in real `foo()` function (actually GA tracking)